# Extract frame of gif with graphicsmagick in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert a gif into a png using graphicsmagick on node.js. In their documentation they have the following code:

```
// pull out the first frame of an animated gif and save as png
gm('/path/to/animated.gif[0]')
    .write('/path/to/firstframe.png', function(err){
    if (err) print('aaw, shucks')
})
```

But what if I read the data not from a file, but from a stream or buffer? There I do not have to give a path and therefore cannot append the [0].

What I need is something like this:

```
gm(streamOrBuffer).extractFrame(0)
    .write('/path/to/firstframe.png', function(err){
    if (err) print('aaw, shucks')
})
```

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196488/how-can-i-extract-the-first-frame-of-a-gif-and-save-it-as-a-png-using-graphicsma), but the poster ended up drawing the gif on a canvas to extract the first frame on the client side.

I could not find any gm command that looked like it could do what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/blob/7c7dd392d9b7a887a04dd2fef64c3a90958c82a2/lib/args.js#L14-L18) you can use `.selectFrame(0)`.

```
gm(streamOrBuffer)
    .selectFrame(0)
    .write('/path/to/firstframe.png', function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it! They even have an issue to add it to the docs [here](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/461).

Comment: Thanks for inspiration, it helped me answering similar question about PDF first page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276310/4536543