# Thumbnail the first page of a pdf from a stream in GraphicsMagick

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, thumbnails, graphicsmagick

I know how to use GraphicsMagick to make a thumbnail of the first page of a pdf if I have a pdf file and am running `gm` locally. I can just do this:

```
gm(pdfFileName + "[0]")
  .background("white")
  .flatten()
  .resize(200, 200)
  .write("output.jpg", (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
```

If I have a file called `doc.pdf` then passing `doc.pdf[0]` to `gm` works beautifully.

But my problem is I am generating thumbnails on an AWS Lambda function, and the Lambda takes as input data streamed from a source S3 bucket. The relevant slice of my lambda looks like this:

```
// Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
async.waterfall([
  function download(next) {
    s3.getObject({
      Bucket: sourceBucket,
      Key: sourceKey
    },
    next);
  },

  function transform(response, next) {
    gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {       // <--- gm USED HERE
    .
    .
    .
```

Everything works, but for multipage pdfs, `gm` is generating a thumbnail from the last page of the pdf. How do I get the `[0]` in there? I did not see a page selector in the [gm documentation](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/) as all their examples used filenames, not streams I believe there should be an API, but I have not found one.

(Note: the `[0]` is really important not only because the last page of multipage PDFs are sometimes blank, but I noticed when running `gm` on the command line with large pdfs, the `[0]` returns very quickly while without the `[0]` the whole pdf is scanned. On AWS Lambda, it's important to finish quickly to save on resources and avoid timeouts!)

Comment: one possible solution that includes some redundancy would be store s3 object locally within `/tmp/` folder (every lambda has access to `/tmp` directory), and then use `gm(pdfFileName + "[0]")`. in other words download file from s3 into lambda temporary folder, and run the `gm` same way you would run it locally.

Comment: Thanks, I can give this a try, but I'm surprised there's no function or function parameter. Perhaps the bounty will attract some attention. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.selectFrame()` method, which is equivalent to specifying `[0]` directly in file name.

In your code:

```
function transform(response, next) {
    gm(response.Body)
        .selectFrame(0)       // <--- select the first page
        .size(function(err, size) {
        .
        .
        .
```

Don't get confused about the name of function. It work not only with *frames* for GIFs, but also works just fine with *pages* for PDFs.

Checkout this function [source](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/blob/e715cbdaacad21504fc04f6933be5cae1812501e/lib/args.js#L14) on GitHub.

Credits to [@BenFortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615209/ben-fortune) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500877/4536543) to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35500644/4536543) about GIFs first frame. I've took it as inspiration and tested this solution with PDFs, it actually works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, I was hoping it would be that easy. I must have browsed all the source files in `lib` _except_ for args! (I did grep for `[0]` but wouldn't you know of _course_ it would have been a variable.) Makes perfect sense.